# Azure Search Keeping Record of Documents Satisfying Queries

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Is there any way through Elastic Search or Lucene metadata, to store a count of how many times a particular document has satisfied queries even though one has not recalled the document for processing.

For example, say you issue a query and get 100 results. You process the first 10 and not go any further. We would like to flag ALL the documents (100) that satisfied the search criteria for later analysis.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Azure Search does not expose this information (and neither does Elasticsearch or Lucene). However, we're working on building better ranking models, and we're thinking about capturing (and potentially exposing) this type of data.

We'd be very interested in learning more about your scenario. Could you email me at eugenesh at the usual Microsoft domain? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Hope to see such feature real soon.